# Linux: Generate installer with dependencies

Tags: qt, opencv, ubuntu, cmake, installation

I would like to create an installer for my program, which uses OpenCV and some Qt libraries. I also want to make sure that all dependencies are included in the installer so that anyone could easily install my program without installing OpenCV and/or Qt.

I did some research and it seems that the easiest way to do so would be using [Qt Installer Framework](http://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/ifw-overview.html). I have the following CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

# Add folder where are supportive functions
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

# Include qt basic functions
include(QtCommon)

# Include qt current directories in order to use promoted objects
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/modules/app)
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/modules/cores)

# Basic info about project
project(SSAT VERSION 1.0)

# Set PROJECT_VERSION_PATCH and PROJECT_VERSION_TWEAK to 0 if not present, needed by add_project_meta
fix_project_version()

file(GLOB APP_GUI_FILES "modules/app/*.ui")
file(GLOB APP_SOURCE_FILES "modules/app/*.cpp")
file(GLOB CORE_SOURCE_FILES "modules/core/*.cpp")
file(GLOB CORE_INCLUDE_FILES "modules/core/*.h")
file(GLOB CMT_SOURCE_FILES "modules/tracker/*.cpp")
file(GLOB CMT_INCLUDE_FILES "modules/tracker/*.h")

add_project_meta(META_FILES_TO_INCLUDE)

set(RESOURCE_FILES ssat.qrc)

find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenCV COMPONENTS opencv_core opencv_imgproc opencv_imgcodecs opencv_highgui REQUIRED)
find_path(OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIR "opencv/cv.h" PATHS "${OpenCV_DIR}" PATH_SUFFIXES "include" DOC "")

# If the package has been found, several variables will
# be set, you can find the full list with descriptions
# in the OpenCVConfig.cmake file.
# Print some message showing some of them
message(STATUS "OpenCV library status:")
message(STATUS "    version: ${OpenCV_VERSION}")
message(STATUS "    libraries: ${OpenCV_LIBS}")
message(STATUS "    include path: ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}")


# source_group("UI Files" FILES ${UI_FILES})
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}_CORE ${CORE_SOURCE_FILES} ${CORE_INCLUDE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_CORE ${OpenCV_LIBS})
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}_CORE PUBLIC modules/core/)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}_CMT ${CMT_SOURCE_FILES} ${CMT_INCLUDE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_CMT ${OpenCV_LIBS})
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}_CMT PUBLIC modules/tracker/)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${OS_BUNDLE} # Expands to WIN32 or MACOS_BUNDLE depending on OS
    ${APP_GUI_FILES} ${APP_SOURCE_FILES} ${META_FILES_TO_INCLUDE} ${RESOURCE_FILES}
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${OpenCV_LIBS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_NAME}_CORE)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_NAME}_CMT)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} pthread)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIR})

qt5_use_modules(${PROJECT_NAME} Widgets)
```

Since [Qt Installer Framework](http://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/ifw-overview.html) demonstrates how to create an an installer from a Qt Project (.pro) instead of a CMake file, I would like to know if it is possible to create an installer from a CMake project in such a way that all its dependencies are included.

Comment: You might want to look into some modern standalone Linux application packaging alternatives like [snap](http://snapcraft.io/) or [flatpak](http://flatpak.org/) or [appimage](http://appimage.org/).

Comment: What is actually your question?

Comment: Since Qt Installer Framework demonstrates how to create an an installer from a Qt Project (.pro) instead of a CMake file, I would like to know if it is possible to create an installer from a CMake project in such a way that all its dependencies are included.

Comment: Beside Snap or Flatpak it is not common to include all dependencies in "installers". That's how it works for Windows and maybe macOS. On Linuces, people prefer packages (RPM or Deb).